How to Ensure Python Entry Points Use Virtual Environment Shebang When Installing Module in Editable Mode with pyproject.toml?
I have a python module and a venv which I use specifically for installing its dependencies. I install my module using pip install -e .. This worked fine using setup.py. Then I saw a deprecation warning for editable mode advising to use pyproject.toml instead. Now installing the module creates my entry points in .local/bin with a shebang pointing to my global python installation : #!/usr/bin/python.
Changing the shebang manually to #!/usr/bin/env python takes care of the problem but is not ideal. I also reverted back to setup.py which indeed works fine and installs everything in my venv's bin folder. So I guess I just keep it that way until an update breaks it ? Or is there something to do with the toml file ?

Are you sure it was pip from the venv, not from ~/.local/bin?

Yes I checked multiple times

type pip? pip --version?

path/to/venv/bin/python -m pip install --editable path/to/project

[Not an answer: I'm (ab)using the answer box to provide a formatted comment]
$ mktmpenv -p python3.13 # I love virtualenvwrapper
$ cd ~/tmp/
$ git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/Lunarmagpie/busywork.git # Found by scanning through https://github.com/search?q=pyproject.toml&type=repositories
$ cd busywork
$ pip install -e .

The package creates a script busywork. The script resides in my virtualenv's bin:
$ cdvirtualenv
$ cd bin/
$ head -1 busywork 
#!/home/phd/.virtualenvs/tmp-ebe38ad06d6fb9/bin/python

I.e., the script was created in the right place and has the right shebang pointed to the python in the venv. Ok, no problems so far?

Indeed, I tried it and it works on both my machines. Maybe it's a setting in my pyproject.toml. The investigation continues...

@MaximeRenault Can you show your repository if it's public? or provide a [mre]?

The repo is private, but I'm working on a MRE
